# Justify alignment the inside of a cell with tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, justification

I was making a table with the `tabularx` environment, and I do not know what package or command I am missing, but I´m not capable of have a justify text inside the cells on the table, hope you could help.

Here is the problem and the right allign cells:

[image]

And here the code for that table:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rX}
\\
 \textbf{Descripción:}& Primera toma de contacto con el centro, el departamento de FyQ, así como tres de los grupos de mi tutora.\\
  \\
 \textbf{Desarrollo y Ejecución:}& Primeramente estuve en una reunión de departamento, aunque no se trataron los temas habituales, fue más una introducción y presentación de cómo actuaban y las medidas COVID. Después fuimos a un 2º de Bachillerato, clase donde se empezó con problemas de Ácido/Base e hidrólisis, una clase muy grande pero en general, sin ningún incidente. En el recreo nos recibió el equipo directivo, para informarnos del protocolo COVID y de los distintos servicios informáticos de que disponían. Seguidamente tuvimos clase de guardia, donde coincidimos con varios profesores y me explicaron cómo se distribuyen las mismas, así como la rotación. También acudí a un examen de FyQ de un curso de 1º Bachillerato, y a última hora estuve en una clase de 3ºESO, donde se notó mucho el cambio de actitud de los alumnos, con algunos un poco ``conflictivos'', que eminentemente consistió en resolución de problemas.   \\
   \\
 \textbf{Participación activa:}& En las primeras clases me limité a observar cómo se desarrollaban las sesiones, así como el comportamiento de los alumnos. Después, tanto en la guardia como en la hora del examen, mi tutora me fue explicando cómo se organizaba para llevar al día los contenidos que tenía que dar en cada grupo, dónde se había quedado para el día siguiente, la rúbrica de notas, incluso me dejó echar un vistazo a los exámenes de unos alumnos de 2º Bachillerato de la parte de Cinética Química y Equilibrio. Por último, en la clase de 3º ESO aproveché que estaban hablando de los diferentes isótopos del carbono para explicar que eso es una de las pruebas que confirman que el cambio climática está causado por el ser humano, así como que muchos de los compuestos que se determinan para el etiquetado alimentario se miden con técnicas que usan de estos isótopos. \\
    \\
  \textbf{Reflexión y Análisis:}& Fue un día intenso en la que pude ver a grupos de niveles muy dispares y cómo es la actitud de la profesora en cada caso, que como es obvio no puede ser la misma.    \\
     \\
   \textbf{Propuesta de innovación:}& En el tema de ácido/base, se podría haber empleado alguna aplicación como Desmos para ejemplificar mejor las aproximaciones que se hacen en la ecuación de 2º grado a resolver, mientras que en el curso de 3º ESO se podría haber preparado algún vídeo que explicase con imágenes (y no sólo de palabra) la importancia de los isótopos.   \\
     \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Finally, here the packages I am using in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referencias}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=green!3,colframe=green!75!black}
\newtcolorbox{mybox2}{,colback=blue!3!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cancel}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Apart from your text not being justified but left aligned instead, there is an even more serious problem with your table: It is too large for the page and therefore cut off. Probably, you could switch to a `description` environment (customized using the `enumitem` package) to also overcome this issue?

Comment: The culprit for the left aligned/ragged-right text in your `X` txpe column is the use of `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}`.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- As @leandriis has already pointed out in comment, the reason you're getting ragged-right layout in the right-hand column is because you're loading the `ragged2e` package with the option `document`. Either get rid of that option or change `X` to `>{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X`.
- Your table code makes the table too tall to fit inside the text block. The main culprit is the fact that you're not allowing the material in the left-hand column to line wrap, which results in that column rather wide -- and hence the right-hand column being rather narrow. I would change from an `r` column type to `>{\RaggedLeft\bfseries}p{\mylen}`, where `\mylen` is set to the width of `\textbf{Propuesta de}}`.
- Adding a full blank lines between groups seems excessive. I'd load the `booktabs` package and replace the four `\\` line spacers with `\addlinespace`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%% I've commented out all preamble instructions not relevant
%%% relevant for the table at hand
\usepackage[letterpaper, hmargin=3cm, vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % <-- new
%\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
%\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Referencias}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%%%\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure} % 'subfigure' package is deprecated!
%%%\usepackage{cite} %% don't load both 'cite' and 'natbib'

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=green!3,colframe=green!75!black}
%\newtcolorbox{mybox2}{,colback=blue!3!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}}
%\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \addlinespace macro
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbf{Propuesta de}} % desired width of left-hand column

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       >{\RaggedLeft\bfseries}p{\mylen} 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X  @{}}
Descripción & Primera toma de contacto con el centro, el departamento de FyQ, así como tres de los grupos de mi tutora.\\
\addlinespace
Desarrollo y Ejecución & Primeramente estuve en una reunión de departamento, aunque no se trataron los temas habituales, fue más una introducción y presentación de cómo actuaban y las medidas COVID\@. Después fuimos a un 2º de Bachillerato, clase donde se empezó con problemas de Ácido/Base e hidrólisis, una clase muy grande pero en general, sin ningún incidente. En el recreo nos recibió el equipo directivo, para informarnos del protocolo COVID y de los distintos servicios informáticos de que disponían. Seguidamente tuvimos clase de guardia, donde coincidimos con varios profesores y me explicaron cómo se distribuyen las mismas, así como la rotación. También acudí a un examen de FyQ de un curso de 1º Bachillerato, y a última hora estuve en una clase de 3ºESO, donde se notó mucho el cambio de actitud de los alumnos, con algunos un poco ``conflictivos'', que eminentemente consistió en resolución de problemas. \\
 \addlinespace
Participación activa & En las primeras clases me limité a observar cómo se desarrollaban las sesiones, así como el comportamiento de los alumnos. Después, tanto en la guardia como en la hora del examen, mi tutora me fue explicando cómo se organizaba para llevar al día los contenidos que tenía que dar en cada grupo, dónde se había quedado para el día siguiente, la rúbrica de notas, incluso me dejó echar un vistazo a los exámenes de unos alumnos de 2º Bachillerato de la parte de Cinética Química y Equilibrio. Por último, en la clase de 3º ESO aproveché que estaban hablando de los diferentes isótopos del carbono para explicar que eso es una de las pruebas que confirman que el cambio climática está causado por el ser humano, así como que muchos de los compuestos que se determinan para el etiquetado alimentario se miden con técnicas que usan de estos isótopos. \\
  \addlinespace
Reflexión y Análisis & Fue un día intenso en la que pude ver a grupos de niveles muy dispares y cómo es la actitud de la profesora en cada caso, que como es obvio no puede ser la misma. \\
   \addlinespace
Propuesta de innovación & En el tema de ácido/base, se podría haber empleado alguna aplicación como Desmos para ejemplificar mejor las aproximaciones que se hacen en la ecuación de 2º grado a resolver, mientras que en el curso de 3º ESO se podría haber preparado algún vídeo que explicase con imágenes (y no sólo de palabra) la importancia de los isótopos.
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```